# Помогите написать условие сравнение столбцов матрицы

Tags: c++, сортировка, матрицы

> Столбцы должны сравниваться на идентичность, если идентичны более 3, то выводится сообщение bad

```
char mas[11][11];

for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) { //Создаем рандомные значения для строк
    for (int k = 0; k < 11; k++) {

        mas[i][k] = (rand() % ('j' - 'a' + 1)) + 'a';
        cout << mas[i][k];

    }
    cout << endl;
}

char z;
bool a, b, c;

for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) { //Создаем условия сортировки
    for (int k = 0; k < 11; k++) {
        if (mas[i][k] == mas[i][k + 1]) {
            a = true; // вот тут должно быть условие



        }
        if (mas[i][k] < mas[i][k + 1]) {
            z = mas[i][k + 1];
            cout << z;
        }


    }

}

system("pause");
return 0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже, у вас что-то с размерностью массива напутано. Судя по циклам, должно быть:

```
char mas[40][11];
```

А что касается условия, сделайте счетчик:

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) { //Создаем условия сортировки
    for (int k = 0; k < 11; k++) {
        if (k < 10 && mas[i][k] == mas[i][k + 1]) {
            count++; // вот тут должно быть условие
        }
        else {
            count = 0;
        }
        if (count >= 3) {
            // Нашли три подряд идентичных
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: `mas[i][k + 1])` в конце цикла выйдет за предели массива

Comment: @Senior Pomidor, исправил, хотя, это совсем никак не относится к заданному вопросу...

Answer (score 0):

1) Заполнение массива:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) { //Создаем рандомные значения для строк
        for (int k = 0; k < 11; k++) {

            mas[i][k] = (rand() % ('j' - 'a' + 1)) + 'a';
            cout << mas[i][k];

        }
        cout << endl;
    }
```

А тебя не смущает, что матрица 11x11, а ты заполняешь сразу до 40 строки?
Ты бы хотя бы размеры матрицы в виде константы задал и по константе в цикле бы обрабатывал

```
const int columnsAmount = 11;
const int rowsAmount = 11;
```

2) самое простое было бы сделать одномерный массив одномерных массивов (вектора, например) - тогда можно было бы сравнивать автоматическими средствами, просто передавая указатели на вектора в стандартные средства

это возможно и быстрее бы работало

3) в твоем случае:

```
int equelColumnsAmount = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < columnsAmount - 1; i++) { //Создаем условия сортировки

    bool isEquel = true;

    for (int j = i + 1; j < columnsAmount; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < rowsAmount; k++) {
            if (mas[i][k] != mas[j][k]) {
                isEquel = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (isEquel == true)
            equelColumnsAmount ++;
    }
}

if (equelColumnsAmount >= 3)
    std::cout << 'bad';
```

т.е.

1) в цикле проходим по всем колонкам, которые надо сравнить друг с другом

2) каждую колонку сравниваем со всеми последующими (с предыдущими уже раньше было сравнение)

3) сравниваем поэлементно, если элементы не совпадают - сразу прекращаем проверку, ибо колонки тогда не похожи и не надо проводить дополнительных сравнений

твой алгоритм выполнит максимум `rowsAmount * columnsAmount * columnsAmount / 2` сравнений, но можно оптимизировать - выйти из алгоритма при достижении счётчика `equelColumnsAmount` критического значения

Comment: 10x10 получится. Зачем -1 там?

Comment: @Herrgott, мы сравниваем текущий столбец со следующими. Какой следующий после 11? Никакого. Поэтому в первом цикле максимальный текущий столбец меньше максимального столбца на 1, чтобы было с чем сравнивать (грубо говоря на последнем этапе сравнение только с одним столбцом будет)

Comment: @zhihar само сообщение в строке занимает 10 символов + закрывающий ноль в массиве строк, поэтому 11

Comment: @Uncle, э... так это строки? т.е. массив строк и надо найти несовпадающие строки, а я относился как к массиву чисел в дапазоне от -127 до 128

впрочем это ничего не меняет, можно просто добавить при сравнении `row` проверку на ноль - как только она возникает - прекращаем проверку, если ноль не в обоих столбцах - проверка провалена

Comment: @zhihar То, что это строки указывает (rand() % ('j' - 'a' + 1)) + 'a'; , тем более, что это ограниченные алфавитом в 10 символов строки, хотя даже с таким ограничением алфавитом, с ними можно работать и в int, используя код символа ASCII

Comment: @Uncle, если строки одного размера, то код остается тем же, что я привёл, впрочем даже без этого (если строки разные) проверка сработает потому что 0 с ненулем будет сравниваться